# Could anyone explain how Account account is a class attribute in this case? How is "Account" a type?

Tags: java, oop

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N4oS.png)This is a Java issue. I always knew that class attribute/fields could be type Int, String, Double but how is "Account" a type, such that Account savingsAccount is a class attribute? Can anyone explain me this. I do not know if there is a specific topic related to this in Java but I do not understand this. For example, the account class has attributes such as "type" like savings/loan that is type string. It also has balance which is type double. But how is the same account a class attribute in the Customer class? I mean logically I understand that a customer has an account but why is the type "Account" in this case? Shouldn't it be a string? Please kindly explain this to me. I have attached 2 images. [This image has the relevant class attributes and constructors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLe0h.png)

I did not quite understand the class attributes section of the Customer Class. Could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: If you define an instance variable `String myString`, it has a type of String, right? So, if you define an instance variable `Account myAccount`, what type would it have? (If you don't understand what `Account myAccount` means, I suggest you read a beginner-oriented tutorial first.)

Comment: Also note that Java is case-sensitive, `Account` is not the same as `account`.

Comment: Besides that: please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Comment: Thank you for linking to that, @Robert! I'm on my phone, and was too lazy to look up the link. :)

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/442830/best-practice-avoid-naming-class-and-field-the-same may be helpful

Comment: @yshavit I understand that Account account has a type - Account but my question is aren't we supposed to use primitive types when defining class attributes like- int, string, double? Or can we use other types as well such as in this case where the type of account is "Account"? I am a bit unsure because I don't think I was taught this. Earlier I only knew that class attribute types can only be primitive.

Comment: *"I quite did not understand the code."*  - What code?  There is no code!  One image shows some requirements.  The second one shows some type signatures.  But there is no `Account account` there.  OK, so you seem to be rather confused ... but the way that you've written your question makes it really hard to understand what you are confused about and what you are actually asking.

Comment: *"Earlier I only knew that class attribute types can only be primitive."* - Ah.  Finally we get to the source of your confusion.  That knowledge is **incorrect**.  A class attribute (or field as they are more normally called in Java) can have a primitive type OR a reference type.  The reference types are array types, classes, interfaces, enums (and records in Java 16 or later).   So there is absolutely nothing wrong with declaring a field as `Account account`.

Comment: @StephenC I apologize as this is my first time posting a question. I have editted my question again. I have attached 2 images. The first one is the question specification and the second one is the plan to solve it. You will notice that in the Fields section of the customer, it's written Account savingsAccount. I did not understand how "Account" is a type here but I get that logically in real-life scenario.

Comment: `Account` is a type because it is a class and classes are types.  (In fact, they are reference types; see above.)  `Account savingsAccount` is declaring a field called `savingsAccount` whose type is `Account`.  I don't think we can explain it to you in simpler terms.  Maybe you should talk to your teacher?

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the clarification. I understand now as this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from the business requirement, as described in the image you attached, an account should contain two properties including type and balance.

The object in java would look like

```
class Account {
  private string type;
  private int balance;

  // omit getter/setter
}

class User {
  private Account account;

  // omit getter and setter

  public Account getAccount() {
    return this.account;
  }
}
```

This a business scenario

- you want to get a user's account's balance. You code looks like

```
User user = new User();
user.getAccount().getBalance();
```

- you want to get a user's account's type. You code looks like

```
user.getAccount().getType();
```

To answer your question, if you define an Account as string, you cannot retrieve the balance and type flexiablely.

This is the thinking of object orientied design. Each object points to the real world should be considered as an object. Each object contains multiple attributes.